# Smoothing intraday data when only looking at a certain time range

Tags: time-series, exponential-smoothing

I have an intraday price series (5 minute) over several months. I want to smooth the data using an ema but also i am only interested in analysing the series between certain time periods eg between 8am and 12am (morning). I was thinking of doing this in  a primitive form:

1. Take returns (1 period returns)
2. Remove data outside of time range
3. Remove data outside of "x" std.dev (not for erroneous data but to help with general predicatbility)
4. Apply smoothing
5. Create lagged series
6. Normalize the data between -1 and +1
7. Apply statistical learning technique

Is this valid when only looking at a certain range of time periods or is there a more robust approach?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information.  What is the underlying time frequency on which you would be calculating returns (your step 1), and what is the return period you would be calculating?  Presumably step #4 is to remove probably erroneous data, in which case you should do it before smoothing.  Why would you create lagged data (step #5)?  What normalization do you contemplate that could be performed all the way at step #6?

Comment: I have updated my question based on some of your comments. Step 5 is that I was considering training the next return value on the  lagged ema values x number of lags back and see if they provide meaningful prediction of the current value. Where I then optimise the ema length hence alpha and the number of lags. Am I getting this wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with what you propose: Cropping time to specific "windows" can produce valid alpha models.  For example, with most market data "time" is already naturally cropped to the hours the market is open and/or actively traded.  And practitioners know that during market hours there are characteristics unique to the open, midday, close, etc., and so there are alpha models based on data drawn only from those time windows.

Without getting into the nuances of your model we couldn't say whether there is a more robust approach to it, but if you want to delve into that https://quant.stackexchange.com/ would probably be a more productive venue.